# Share WindowLevel,Zoom,Pan between VTKWidgets with Dicom Images

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, vtk, dicom

I am new into `VTK` library currently developing some application with `Qt 5.4` and `VTK 6.1` for viewing native `DICOM` images. I have 4 `QVTKWidget2` widgets each window is showing data from Serie: Axial, Coronal, Sagittal and 3D MPR and MIP.

For showing axial coronal and sagittal data i use `vtkResliceImageViewer` for MPR i use `vtkImagePlaneWidget` and for MIP i use `vtkVolume` with `vtkSmartVolumeMapper`.

My question is how can i achieve so all widgets to share the Zoom, Pan and WindowLevel so when i change window level on one Widget the changes are applied to all other windows. Similar with Pan and Zoom tools.

Answer (score 2):

you can handle such like things, with signals/slots. For example you can define a signal which named 'zoom_in'. 
Now if you do an an zoom in in widget1, it throws the signal 'zoom_in'.
And the other widgets catches the signal. 
If the widget catched the signal, make a slot for doZoom_in for widget 2,3,4.

Example:
[image]

look documentation:
[Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: Yea i know very well about Qt Signal&Slot mechanism the thing is how to catch that event of zoom begins from `VTK` library (the zoom odd) so i can emit it and connect to a slot with other widgets, Also with the Pan tool how to catch the new location after pan and similar with Windowlevel 

Anyway thanks for your answer.